# cannot do rollover image when image is on top of another image

Tags: css

Berlow is simple code to do rollover image with the image planced on top of another image.  Problem is, the image rollover occurs, but the original image is still displaying and is offset similarly (position), ie., below and to the right.  The image size for the two rollover images are exactly the same.  Thanks if you can provide some feedback...

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
#header {
    height: 500px;
    width: 900px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
#button1 {
    position: absolute;
    'display: inline-block;
    top: 100px;
    left: 50px;
}
a:hover {       
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    top: 100px;
    left: 50px;
    width: 122px;
    height: 28px;
    background-image: none;
    background-image: url('images/buttonRed1.gif');
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="header">
  <img src="images/large.jpg"/>
  <a id="myLink" href="abc.html">
  <div id="button1" style="background-image:url(images/buttonRed2.gif); width: 122px; height: 28px;"></div></a>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this instead

```
#button1{
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    top: 100px;
    left: 50px;
    background-image: url('images/large.jpg');
}

#button1:hover {
    background-image: url('images/buttonRed1.gif');  no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, so you should give your css some major changes. Consider the following:

1. Which should have the changing background image? The button or the link? Because you placed the first image inside the link, and the second inside the div...
2. You should try providing some [jsfiddles](http://jsfiddle.net/) when showing examples. It hastens the process of responding.

   Anyway, I removed the entire button div and placed all the css on the link and then placed the following css on the link:

```css
#myLink{
    background-image:url('some/image.jpg');  
    width:122px;  
    height: 28px;  
    background-size: 122px 28px;  
    position: absolute;  
    display: inline-block;  
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    top: 100px;  
    left: 50px;  
}

#myLink:hover {    
    background-image: url('another/image.jpg');
}
```

here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Bv5R8/1/).